# any yworks uml doclet users out there who understand distinction between bold/heavy arrows and lighter ones?

Tags: uml, javadoc

I use this uml graphing doclet a lot and it is really cool. But it generates diagrams i don't fully understand.. In particular sometimes my packages have thick arrows between them, sometimes dependencies are represented by thinner arrows.. 
 like in this example >

[image]

[External link for larger view](http://www.yworks.com/img/ydoc/overview_dotnet_DBT_ACTSLP.png):

i have not figured out the difference in the types of dependencies that causes the doclet to choose one representation vs. the other.  anyone else figure this out ?
thx in advance
 cb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For package dependency diagrams, yDoc keeps count of how many individual dependencies exist between two packages. For every five dependencies, the thickness of the corresponding connection is increased by one pixel (up to a seven pixel maximum).

In short: The thicker the line, the "stronger" the dependency.

Comment: Thanks, Sebastian - love your product.  Even more now that the community edition is free. keep it up !